# How do I restructure my Macro? Multiple .Find and .FindNext cause error (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a new macro where it looks through a master list of assignments with various tasks in a master workbook, then populates a to-do list for individuals on one sheet in a different workbook, and gives information on these assignments, pulled from the master workbook.

It was going well until I added another Find function, and now it's throwing errors. With some research I've realized it's because I have two Find functions that is assumably ruining the context for the FindNext. So, I sort of understand the theory but I don't know how to practically fix it.

What are some alternatives to get my code working?

Here are screenshots and the code for context:

[image]

^ Master workbook, with sheets Fear, Gender, Happy, RBL, and WholeReport that have information on the subjects

[image]

^ Indiv to-do list

[image]
^ Indiv cleaning notes log

Code:

```
Sub FindTest()
Dim wbMaster As Workbook
Dim wbIndiv As Workbook
Dim wsMaster, wsIndiv As Worksheet
Dim wsICleaning As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRowIndiv, LastRowIClean As Long
Dim FoundRow, FoundCol As Long
Dim FoundRow2 As Long
Dim firstCellAddress As String
Dim rgSearch As Range
Dim aCell As Range
Dim bCell As Range
Dim MergeID As String

Dim sourcePath As String: sourcePath = "C:\Cleaning_Notes_testing\"
Dim strIndiv(1 To 3) As String
Dim i, e
Dim TaskString As String

Set wbMaster = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsMaster = wbMaster.Sheets("Data Tracking Log")
LastRow = Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Row

strIndiv(1) = "Christie"
strIndiv(2) = "Brittany"
strIndiv(3) = "Adeeb"

For Each i In strIndiv
    If i <> "" Then
        With Workbooks.Open(sourcePath & "Cleaning_notes_" & i & ".xlsx")
            Debug.Print i
            Set wbIndiv = ActiveWorkbook
            Set wsIndiv = wbIndiv.Sheets("To-Do")
            Set wsICleaning = wbIndiv.Sheets("Cleaning Notes")

            ' Get search range
                Set rgSearch = wsMaster.Range("E1:L" & LastRow)
                Set aCell = rgSearch.Find(i)

            ' If not found then exit
                If aCell Is Nothing Then
                    Debug.Print "Not found"
                    Exit Sub
                End If

            ' Store first aCell address
                firstCellAddress = aCell.Address
                Debug.Print firstCellAddress

            ' Find all cells containing Name
                Do
                    Debug.Print "Found: " & aCell.Address
                    'Populate To-Do
                    FoundRow = aCell.Row
                    Debug.Print "FoundRow: " & FoundRow
                    FoundCol = aCell.Column
                    Debug.Print "Found Col: " & FoundCol

                    Set aCell = rgSearch.FindNext(After:=aCell)
                    Debug.Print "Found: " & aCell.Address

                    wsIndiv.Activate
                    LastRowIndiv = wsIndiv.Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    wsIndiv.Range("A" & LastRowIndiv).Value = wsMaster.Range("A" & FoundRow).Value
                    wsIndiv.Range("B" & LastRowIndiv).Value = wsMaster.Range("C" & FoundRow).Value
                    wsIndiv.Range("C" & LastRowIndiv).Value = wsMaster.Range("D" & FoundRow).Value
                    wsIndiv.Range("D" & LastRowIndiv).Value = wsMaster.Cells(1, FoundCol).Value
                    MergeID = wsIndiv.Range("A" & LastRowIndiv).Value
                    Debug.Print MergeID
                    TaskString = wsMaster.Cells(1, FoundCol).Value
                    Debug.Print TaskString

                    'Populate indiv Cleaning Notes
                    If TaskString = "Fear" Or TaskString = "Gender" Or TaskString = "Happy" Or TaskString = "RBL" Or TaskString = "WholeReport" Then
                        wsICleaning.Activate
                        LastRowIClean = Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Row + 1

                        wsICleaning.Range("A" & LastRowIClean).Value = wsMaster.Range("A" & FoundRow).Value
                        wsICleaning.Range("B" & LastRowIClean).Value = wsMaster.Range("C" & FoundRow).Value
                        wsICleaning.Range("C" & LastRowIClean).Value = wsMaster.Range("D" & FoundRow).Value
                        wsICleaning.Range("D" & LastRowIClean).Value = TaskString

                        wbMaster.Sheets(TaskString).Activate
                        Set bCell = ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Find(What:=MergeID, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                        FoundRow2 = bCell.Row
                        Debug.Print "FoundRow2: " & FoundRow2
                        Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Range("G" & FoundRow2).Value

                        wsICleaning.Range("E" & LastRowIClean).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & FoundRow2).Value
                    End If


                    wsMaster.Activate

                Loop While firstCellAddress <> aCell.Address
        End With
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `Find()` before the loop ending check

```
    Set aCell = rgSearch.Find(What:=i, After:=aCell)
Loop While firstCellAddress <> aCell.Address
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great now! I knew it was going to be something small :)